# Import error opencv2 : Setup inside anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

So, I have had trouble importing cv2 for a while now. 
I followed this tutorial 
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

The only difference is that I did the setup in an Anaconda environment

It installed open cv2 successfully and is also present in the site-packages
and yet it shows an import error.

```
((tensorflow)) Meghas-MacBook-Air:~ Megha$ python

Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.


>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Comment: have you installed using `conda install opencv`?

Comment: yes, I tried that as well. I also tried doing pip install opencv , but that didn't work as well!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Uninstall the existing anaconda and re-install it again.

Copy the file from Opencv - build - python - 2.7 - x64 - cv2.pyd and paste it in the below path

C:\Users\thomas.a\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\Lib\site-packages

Now restart anaconda and launch spider - everything should work fine.